# code coloring in dreamweaver like aptana studio 3?

Tags: aptana, dreamweaver

I'm wondering if anyone has found a dark code-coloring theme for dreamweaver that's modeled after that in aptana studio 3? I've searched on this forum and elsewhere, and I've seen solutions to achieve DW code-coloring in aptana, but not the reverse; the default aptana 3 color theme is very pleasing to the eye.

thanks for any direction here; I may just go ahead and make one myself, in which case I'll share it here.

Answer (score 2):

I made it to look like Aptana Studio. :) (Dreamweaver CS6)
Not 100% looks like that but still I think It's worth sharing it.
It will work in CSS, JS, PHP and HTML only.

[Dreamweaver CS6 Aptana Studio like color theme](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1848610/ColorsDark.xml)

Answer (score 1):

You would think that someone would have created an extension to allow easy importing of color schemes by now but that still doesn't appear to be the case.

You can always set it yourself by going to *Edit | Preferences | Code Coloring* and setting the options there.  It's time consuming but certainly possible to replicate Aptana's settings.

Alternately, if you Google for it you should find several people offering a dark-themed colors.xml file to download from their site.  You can backup your file located in either

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver\en_US\Configuration\CodeColoring
```

or

```
/Users/%name%/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver/%localization(en_US)%/Configuration/CodeColoring
```

for Windows and Mac respectively and replace it with the downloaded version.  That will change your DW interface to use the color settings in the other file.

Comment: thanks for the feedback jcl1178-- good point about the dw extension; it is surprising that one doesn't seem to exist. I've tried several of the "dark themes" available via google searches, but I've yet to find one that I'm totally happy with; if I do end up manually creating an aptana-inspired set of colors, I'll certainly provide a github link for others (I'm actually debating switching to Aptana altogether...)